# Menu jumps on hover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm building a menu using bootstrap 4m but I ran into an issue I can't figure out.

```css
header > nav {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
    padding-top: 1.6rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #504843;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #262423;
    border-bottom: .3rem solid #ff5f06;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

.navbar-nav > li:last-child {
    margin-right: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
       <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I added an orange line (border-bottom) on hover. When I hover over a menu item, the entire menu jumps up a little bit.

How can I avoid this jumping?
Thanks

Comment: that's because of the `href` attribute on each link, it points to `#` which will "mean" return to the top of the page. To avoid that, you either prevent the default  behavior  using `JavaScript` or assign real links to each `href` attribute or assign to each `href` attribute a `JavaScript` `pseudo-protocol` like: `href="javascript: void(0);"` this will prevent the jumping but it's not recommended to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see working example here:
jsfiddle.net/n5f2b4qk/

You have "Jumps" because of the border-bottom: .3rem solid #ff5f06;

There are 2 approaches to avoid it.

1. set border in :after element (as in example)

   .navbar-nav > li > a {
       font-size: 1.4rem;
       color: #504843;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: .1rem;
       font-weight: 700;
       margin-right: 2rem;
       position: relative;
   }

   .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
   .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
       background: none;
       font-size: 1.4rem;
       color: #262423;
       letter-spacing: .1rem;
   }

   .navbar-nav > li > a:hover:after, 
   .navbar-nav > li > a:focus:after {
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       display: block;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       height: .3rem;
       background:  #ff5f06;
   }
2. Other option is to set transparent border for a element and change color with hover.